# SPARQL query on dbpedia: Find women who have husbands younger than them

Tags: sparql, ontology, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am working on a fun query. In [dbpedia](https://dbpedia.org/sparql), I want to find records of females who have married younger males. Or,alternatively, husbands who had wives older than them.

I came up this this SPARQL query. Sadly it returns too few records, only n = 3.

```
# I always add these for easier commandline querying
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
prefix dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
prefix dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
prefix exo: <http://example.org/ontology/> 
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
 
SELECT  ?husband ?husbandBirthDate ?wife ?wifeBirthDate 
WHERE {
# there are 300000 triples that use dbp:spouse 
# unfortunately very few have spouses which are also in dbpedia
# and for  those partners  the birthDate occurs even more rarely in dbpedia

{
   ?husband dbp:spouse  ?wife .
   ?husband dbp:gender ?husbandGender.
     FILTER(str(?husbandGender) = "male") 
   ?husband dbp:birthDate ?husbandBirthDate .

   ?wife    dbp:birthDate ?wifeBirthDate .
   ?wife dbp:gender ?wifeGender.
   FILTER(str(?wifeGender) = "female") .
   FILTER (?husbandBirthDate > ?wifeBirthDate)

} 
UNION 
# there are ~1400 triples that use dbo:husband which means "hasHusband"
 {
 ?wife dbp:husband  ?husband .
 ?husband dbo:birthDate ?husbandBirthDate .
 ?wife    dbo:birthDate ?wifeBirthDate .
 FILTER (?husbandBirthDate > ?wifeBirthDate)
 }
UNION 
# there are ~1300 triples that use dbo:wife  which means "hasWife"
 {
 ?husband dbp:wife ?wife  .
 ?husband dbo:birthDate ?husbandBirthDate .
 ?wife    dbo:birthDate ?wifeBirthDate .
 FILTER (?husbandBirthDate > ?wifeBirthDate)
 }

}
ORDER BY ?husbandBirthDate
```

Sadly it returns too few records,these three, (currently, 2020):

| husband | husbandBirthDate | wife | wifeBirthDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [http://dbpedia.org/resource/Karel_Kosík](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Karel_Kos%C3%ADk) | 1926-06-26 | [http://dbpedia.org/resource/Růžena_Grebeníčková](http://dbpedia.org/resource/R%C5%AF%C5%BEena_Greben%C3%AD%C4%8Dkov%C3%A1) | 1925-11-01 |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/Keiran_Lee | 1984-01-15 | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Puma_Swede | 1976-09-13 |
| http://dbpedia.org/resource/Keiran_Lee | 1984-01-15 | http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kirsten_Price_(actress) | 1981-11-13 |

What am I doing wrong?

Should I switch to the `foaf` ontology? Do I have to explicitly parse the date with `^^xsd::date`?

> Note: I have my own docker-image of DBpedia, in the  [production version of DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org/sparql) about 25 records are found. Still too few , I think.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but Wikidata has much better data in my experience.
The query I use returns me 22k results. Find it here: https://w.wiki/rc$.

Comment: @valerio-cocchi I know that WIkipedia is much larger and has much better data. (Later I wanted to construct something like your Wikidata query myself, anyway. Thanks for doing this!) -- My main task was getting [my own custom constainer](https://github.com/dbpedia/virtuoso-sparql-endpoint-quickstart) with 60 GB of DBpedia up and running, learning about physical data organisation. Then, as a minor task, learn more about SPARQL. Doing this which is a bit easier with DBPedia's English subj/propert/object names, than with Wikidata's numeric s/o/p codes.